# Magento Custom Page Layouts Not Appearing in Dropdown Menu

Tags: magento

I'm attempting to create a custom page layout for a Magento site I'm building, but having the most difficult time in the world getting the template to actually appear in the dropdown menu when I create a page. I've tried repeatedly, using different sources, to get this to work, and have no idea where to go from here.

The most annoying part of this is that it works just fine on my local copy of Magento. When I move the exact same code to my remote hosting, however, it no longer shows up in the list.

Here's an example of one of the layouts I've tried to create:

/app/code/local/**custom**/**layouts**/etc/config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
     <modules>
        <custom_layouts>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </custom_layouts>
     </modules>
     <global>
        <page>
            <layouts>
                <home_page_layout module="page" translate="label">
                 <label>Home Page Layout</label>
                 <template>page/home-layout.phtml</template>
                </home_page_layout>
           </layouts>
        </page>
    </global>
</config>
```

/app/etc/modules/custom_layouts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
  <custom_layouts>
   <codePool>local</codePool>
   <active>true</active>
  </custom_layouts>
 </modules>
</config>
```

/app/design/frontend/THEME/default/template/page/home-layout.phtml:

```
CODE...
```

Any idea why this might not be properly appearing? I've double checked to see if the theme is correctly set in Magento too, but that didn't affect anything (obviously).

Thank you for any help in advance!

Alex

Comment: This *might* be better asked on the Magento StackExchange

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, it seems there may be caching issue, refresh your store cache.

```
admin->Cache Management->Select All->Select refresh option in action drop-down and press submit.
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.